# How to return current trending hashtags from Instagram API Sharp in C#

Tags: c#, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to use the Instagram API Sharp C# API to try and return a list of currently trending hashtags. I found a page where the feature was added, but I don't think I understand how to implement it.

Here is a link to how the developer said to implement it: https://github.com/ramtinak/InstagramApiSharp/issues/227

Here are the errors I am getting when I add it to my project

```
public static async Task<List<String>> GetPopularTags()
{
     var test = InstaApi.HashtagProcessor.GetTopHashtagMediaListAsync("plant", PaginationParameters.MaxPagesToLoad(1)).Wait();
}
```

I am new to programming in general so it might be a simple fix. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to create an instance of `InstaApi` and use that to grab the list of Hashtags

```
public static IInstaApi api = InstaApiBuilder.CreateBuilder().SetUser(userSession)
                                                                     .UseLogger(new DebugLogger(InstagramApiSharp.Logger.LogLevel.All))
                                                                     .Build();


public static async Task<List<String>> GetPopularTags()
{
      var test = await api.HashtagProcessor.GetTopHashtagMediaListAsync("plant", PaginationParameters.MaxPagesToLoad(1));       
}
```

Also I was using the `.Wait()` method incorrectly. I had to add 'await' in front in order to receive the result properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the way you are calling `GetTopHashtagMediaListAsync`. This is not related to this specific API but rather a misunderstanding of how to use `Task`s in C#.

A little heads-up first: when posting a code-related question here on SO, please provide code and errors/exceptions as text rather than images, whenever possible. It would have been nice to see your code in text format.

Anyhow... The following returns a `Task<IResult<InstaSectionMedia>>`:

```
InstaApi.HashtagProcessor
     .GetTopHashtagMediaListAsync("plant", PaginationParameters.MaxPagesToLoad(1));
```

However, you're calling `Wait()` on it, which doesn't return a value (return type `void`) but blocks the current thread waiting for the `Task` to complete. Doing this you also lose the reference to the task. One solution (although not a proper solution, but just for explanation purposes) is to split it in three steps:

```
// Get/start the task
var task = InstaApi.HashtagProcessor
     .GetTopHashtagMediaListAsync("plant", PaginationParameters.MaxPagesToLoad(1));
// Wait for it to complete
task.Wait();
// Use the result
var result = task.Result;
// ...
```

As mentioned, this is not a great solution because you are essentially blocking the current thread with your call to `Wait()`, which occupies a thread in your application that does nothing but wait. When using `Task`s you usually want to `await` it to utilize the asynchronous features built into C# (in fact you've already prepared your method for it with the `async` keyword). A better way to handle your code would therefore be to combine all three steps above into one `await` statement:

```
var result = await InstaApi.HashtagProcessor
     .GetTopHashtagMediaListAsync("plant", PaginationParameters.MaxPagesToLoad(1));
```

This way you let the application use the thread for other things while it's waiting for the task to complete. Once it's completed, the result is assigned to `result` and the code will continue where it left off.

Comment: Ok thank letting me know about the code blocks, I edited the question with the code. However, I still am recievieving the error. The error however wasnt because of the `.Wait()` part. I just had create an instance of 'InstaApi' and then reference it below. I'll add an answer to my own question with a better explanation